# How to align/center text (in a column) under an image? Css html only. using flexbox or something else

Tags: html, css, grid

Newer to coding and I'm trying to create a mobile first website for reference. I am trying to centre text under three images in my footer. Could someone help me do this? Theres a <h1> and  <p> for every image class. I also will need this centre text on other images throughout the website.

Appreciate your help.

Here's my html of the footer:

```
<section id="main-footer"> 
    <hr>
        <img src="images/image1.png" class="image1" alt="image1" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> image1 </h1>
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
        <img src="images/image2.png"  class="image2" alt="image2" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> image2 </h1>
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p>
        <img src="images/image3" class="image3" alt="image3" width="150" height="125">
        <h1> image3 </h1> 
        <p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p> 


</section>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
 .image1 > h1, p {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: auto;
    align-items: center;

    
    }
```

I tried exchanging .image1 with #main-footer so it would be:

```
 #main-footer > h1, p { }
```

It did not work as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b20edu7a/ Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following styles.
You should set the child image fully take place inside parent div.

```
<div class="parent">        
    <img src="images/forest.png" class="forest" alt="forest" width="150" height="125">
    <h1> From the Forest </h1>
</div>

.parent{
    position: relative;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
       
    h1 {
        display: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I center/align it with the other three images on the page?

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use center tag like this.

```
<div>        
<img src="images/forest.png" class="forest" alt="forest" width="150" height="125">
<center><h1>From the Forest </h1></center> </div>
```